# ASRock UEFI setup utility has no option to disable secure boot

Tags: windows-8.1, uefi, secure-boot

I want to downgrade my computer from Windows 8.1 to Windows 7. I originally had Windows 7 on my desktop, then upgraded to Windows 8, then Microsoft basically forced me to upgrade to Windows 8.1. I was getting tired of Windows 8.1, and want to go back to 7.

My motherboard is an ASRock P67 Extreme4 Gen3 motherboard I bought roughly 2 years ago. I can hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to get into the EFI, but when I go to the Security Tab, there's no option to disable secure boot. This is what my firmware looks like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Yv6RsmI.jpg]

and here is what the same firmware looks like on tutorials that I have tried following:

[image: https://neosmart.net/wiki/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2014/05/ASRock-Secure-Boot.jpeg]

Could someone help me out here? Why is there a difference? Also, are there any subtle things I should know about before I attempt this process of getting Windows 7 working on my Windows 8 computer?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I stumbled upon the perfect article on AskUbuntu.com. SecureBoot doesn't show up because my computer doesn't have it. To figure out if you have SecureBoot or not, run Windows PowerShell as Administrator, then type:

```
Confirm-SecureBootUEFI
```

It will return true, false, or "Cmdlet not supported on this platform". Mine returned with the latter, and thus doesn't have it.

[Link to answer that explained this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)