# can't install windows on pcie SSD that is recognized by existing install of windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd

I'm using windows 7 and an ASRock Extreme4 gen3 mobo.
I have an optane ssd 900p (a PCIe ssd) onto which I am trying to install a fresh install of windows. I formatted the drive and it will read/write files without an issue with my current install of windows.

When I boot from a usb to install windows, the drive does not show up.

When I try to install from my existing install of windows, the drive shows up, but I get the message that it can't be installed on that partition. Here are the errors:

```
Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style.

Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu.
```

Currently, it's formatted in GPT as @MichaelBay suggested.

I tried the diskpart suggestion I found elsewhere on here.

Other drives I have attached to the computer via USB and SATA work fine and are recognized by the installer.

My bios does not have an option to disable secure boot / legacy boot; [this person also had this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/813814/asrock-uefi-setup-utility-has-no-option-to-disable-secure-boot) with the same bios UI

Anyone have any ideas? Super frustrating here, my current version of windows is freezing constantly and I just want to start fresh...

Comment: Windows 7 cannot be installed in UEFI mode from a DVD, a USB stick prepared with the Microsft's tool is required. And any Windows requires MBR for Legacy installs and GPT for UEFI install. Knowing that retrace what you did, then [edit] the question and provide more details if pertinent.

Comment: Didn't work... I edited the question to reflect that new try...

Comment: If you are being told Windows cannot be installed on the selected disk, and you are using GPT partition style, it means you have failed to disable legacy mode.  You will want to delete the existing partitions and allow Windows to recreate the partitions using the MBR partition style, given you don't want to disable legacy mode for some reason.  I suggest using GPT, there isn't a valid reason not to use it, and would is required to use your SSD

Comment: Mine doesn't have that option, as in this post. https://superuser.com/questions/813814/asrock-uefi-setup-utility-has-no-option-to-disable-secure-boot